# PHP IMAP code Not Connecting to Gmail Problem

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

OK so my issue is that I created some code in php to connect to GMAIL I got it to work for POP but not for IMAP and Im not sure what the issue is. While using the pop authhost it produced the connected header, and while using the imap authhost I get a page where it displays a 101 error net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET.

The following is the code Im using:

```
$authhost="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$user="username";
$pass="password";

if ($mbox=imap_open( $authhost, $user, $pass ))
{
    echo "<h1>Connected</h1>\n";
    imap_close($mbox);
}   else
{
    echo "<h1>FAIL!</h1>\n";
}
```

The solutions I tried to fix the problem was enabling ssl, imap extension which were enabled awhile back anyways. Also I disabled my firewall, but it didn't fix the problem either. I restarted my WAMP a couple of times to see if it did anything and that didn't work.

Hopely someone can tell me what Im doing wrong : /

****EDIT*****

**I fixed the issue by reinstalling WAMP and activating the imap module in apache called imagemap and it works :).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by reinstalling WAMP and activating the imap module in apache called imagemap and it works :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure "IMAP Access" is enabled in your GMail settings?

Comment: Yeah I enabled that for sure. Also I noticed that both ports are closed for 993 and 995. So I don't understand while using pop instead: $authhost="{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}"; It works?

Comment: your code works just fine for me without any changes whatsoever. All i did was enabled IMAP and thats it.

Comment: Im going to try on my other gmail account that I have and see what results I get.

Comment: i would suggest that you test your script on an external server/hosting, maybe your ISP is blocking some ports?

Comment: yeah I got a feeling that its blocking the ports here locally at work.

Comment: if thats the case simply try to set up the imap account with any mail client, that should be a good test

Comment: Im using microsoft outlook 2010 with IMAP set at 993 and smtp set as 587 and it works. I think there might be a problem somewhere else that I can't see.